# Is it possible to add python scripts in html?

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to make a project in HTML while i am doing PHP Scripting inside this code, Now what i want to do is to add python scripting in this code otherwise i have to shift my code. Please Help.

Comment: Python is not inherently a templating language like PHP, but it has templating libraries like [jinja](https://palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/). You would use a different language in the templates (not Python). Unfortunately, the question is lacking in detail, so the answer cannot be less vague, either.

Comment: [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_(web_framework)) is maybe what's you're looking for...

Answer (score 1):

I found some interesting solutions that can help you solve your problem, use python in a similar way to PHP. However I can't give you feedback because I've never tried them:

1. [digiweb](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001537/references/r_python_inside_html.htm?TocPath=Categories%7CWeb%20Access%7C_____2)
2. [Skulpt](https://skulpt.org/)

If you try them, leave feedback.

However if you have to do something complex I suggest you use [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/).

I hope to be proved helpful.

Comment: Karigell ??? OMG, this thing has been dead for at least ten years...

Comment: I have removed from my answer. Thanks @brunodesthuilliers